# Why am i not able to set exact values vor java heap space?

Tags: java, heap-memory

When i set the java heap space to -Xms4g -Xmx4g my monitory only shows roughly 3.78 GB allocated for heap space. When set to -Xms2g -Xmx2g it shows 1.93 GB like shown in this picture
[image: heap space]

Where do these values come from?

Comment: It would be good to know which monitor you are using to be able to answer.
From the numbers it seems that the size of -Xmx is calculated not in multiples of 1024, but multiples of 1000, which would be unusual.
You could check that with a `System.out.println("max memory = " + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());`

Comment: Gigabytes vs Gibibytes?

Comment: 1.93 GiB is not 1.93 GB